# Ошибка при добавлении библиотеки lwjgl - no lwjgl64 in java.library.path в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, библиотеки, lwjgl

При добавлении игровой библиотеки **lwjgl**  выбрасывает ошибку:

**no lwjgl64 in java.library.path**

Не помогает:

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("pathToNatives").getAbsolutePath());
```

это тоже не помогает:

```
java -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Никита\Desktop\lwjgl-2.9.3\native\windows"
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at GUI.initializeOpenGL(GUI.java:13)
    at GUI.init(GUI.java:8)
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получилось решить в самой IDE

Заходим в `структуру проекта` > `библиотеки` >

- добавляем `каталог с jar` файлами
- добавляем `каталог с dll` файлами (для    винды)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все запускается, все работает!

Answer (score 1):

Вы столкнетесь с проблемой, когда будете собирать свое приложение вне IDE.

На всякий случай напишу:

Для установки из вне приложения используйте в командной строке:

> -Djava.library.path=Абсолютный путь к папке с DLL

Для установки внутри приложения:

```
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);
    Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
    fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
    fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
```